# Select all users whose birthday is in this week (Monday - Sunday)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display all users whose birthday is within this week (Monday to Sunday). After searching everywhere I was able to get this but it's displaying users from last week and this week also.

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE WEEK(birthday, 0) = WEEK(NOW(), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the second argument for the `WEEK` function.  I think that you want it to be either `3` or `5`.  Based on the documentation.

Setting the mode to `0` would get people whose birthdays are on Sunday in the previous week based on what you are saying in your question.

[image: Screenshot of table of mode values]

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL's function [WEEKOFYEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear). You could use it like this to get users with birthday in current week:

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(birthday) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function [WEEKOFYEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear):

```
SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(birthday) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
```

`WEEKOFYEAR` returns a number in the range 1 to 53.